# Performance on Queries

Tags: c#

I have two different queries which returns me the same object. But the first one takes 12 seconds and the second one takes 2 seconds. I wonder why there is a huge difference in terms of performance?

**slower**

```
var Ids = Repo.Get().Where(x => x.StudentId.Equals(StudentId)).Select(x => x.ClassId).Distinct();
```

**faster**

```
 var Ids = Repo.Get(x => x.StudentId.Equals(StudentId)).Select(x => x.ClassId).Distinct();
```

Comment: What is `Repo` in this case, and does its `Get()` method return an `IQueryable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems very clear to me, assuming that:

- `repo` is an Entity Framework `DbContext`
- `Get()` executes the query on the database (probably with `ToList()`)

First query:

```
repo.Get().Where() // => Get all data from the database and filter the results in memory.
```

Second query:

```
repo.Get(x => x...) // => Filter the data in the database and get only the matching entities
```

So, let's imagine your database has 5000 objects. In the first query you request all those objects and just then filter them on memory. The second query, however, adds a `WHERE` clause to the query on the database, which is much faster.

Comment: @RowlandShaw yes, that's my first sentence :) edited for clarity

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to say because we don't know implementation of your Get() method but probably it take all records from source and Then you are filtering the data. And the other example use specified predicate to select only matching records.